# Make a dropdown box link, depending on dropdown choice + change CSS on dropdown choice

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a dropdown box that has all my options, and I also have a go button, that, when no choice is given, has css style `cursor: not-allowed;`. What I want to do now is make it so that when I click an option on the dropdown, it will a) link the button and b) change the css `cursor` style to default. I know it's some sort of `document.getElementById` but how to I trigger that?
Here's the code I have so far.

```
<select>
<option value=1>Option 1</option>
<option value=2>Option 2</option>
<select>
<a id="link" href="#">
<button style="cursor: not-allowed;" id=nextbutton>GO</button>
</a>
      <script>
        document.getElementById("nextbutton").style.cursor = default
        document.getElementById("link").href = "/link"
      </script>
```

Thanks for any help! (I'm new to JS, sorry.)

Comment: `click` is an event that you need to listen to. get all of the `<option>` element, iterate through each of them and add the event to each one by using `addEventListener('click', function() {  // code here })`

Comment: @CodeCreate
"get all of the ```<option>``` element, iterate through each of them and add the event to each one"
How?
(I'm new to JS, sorry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
change(0);
function change(index)
{
  if(index==1)
  {
    document.getElementById("nextbutton").style.cursor ="default"
document.getElementById("link").href = "/link"
  }
  if(index==0)
  {

    document.getElementById("nextbutton").style.cursor ="not-allowed"
document.getElementById("link").href = "#"

  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<select onchange="change(this.selectedIndex);">
<option value=1>Default</option>
<option value=2>Link</option>
<select>
<a id="link" href="#">
<button style="cursor: not-allowed;" id=nextbutton>GO</button>
</a>
</html>
```